# Using if while iterating over dictionary python

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I am using something similar to:

```
dict = {
          'item_1':['1','2','3'], 
          'item_2':['4','5','6'],
          'item_3':['7','8','9']
        }
for item, value in dict.items():
    dictKey = 'item_1'
    if item == dictKey:
        print value
```

I was hoping someone could explain why I get:

```
item_1 ['1', '2', '3']
item_1 ['1', '2', '3']
item_1 ['1', '2', '3']
```

and any clues on how to just get one of those outputs instead of all of them.

Comment: Your code doesn't match your output.

Comment: Your code prints `['1', '2', '3']`

Comment: Oh my gosh you are right... I just realized I had another for loop giving me repeated results. Wow, I thought it was giving me the value I wanted for each of the dictionary keys. Silly mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't (and don't need to) iterate over a dictionary checking the keys to get a value:

```
# wrong
for k, v in dct.items():
    if k == key:
        return value
```

The Python `dict` (which you shouldn't use as a variable name, by the way) is *designed specifically for this use case* (i.e. access to values via keys) and is much, much faster when used properly:

```
# correct
return dct[key]
```

If you aren't sure whether `key in dct`, use `get`:

```
return dct.get(key) # return None if key not in dct
```

or

```
try:
    return dct[key]
except KeyError:
    # deal with error
```

Comment: iterating over a dictionary to find a key is very bad idea.

Comment: I agree, which is why I said so! I have edited my answer to make this clearer

Comment: sorry, my bad. Still, the key may not be in dictionary, so try...except or dct.get() should be advised

Comment: That does work better! Sorry I have been using python for about a week now and am still trying to get into good habits. Thanks!

Comment: I think a except handler on a dict[key] is more pythonic than a if dict.get(key): value = dict.get(key).  Checking return values is much more like C

Comment: To clarify what @dnlbmn is saying, it's better to use something like `try: return dct[key]; except KeyError: print "The key {} is missing!".format(key)`

Comment: I have now added `try: except:` too